# Team Project Set for TFS in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, tfs, intellij-idea

We have a large TFS source repository with Java source modules organized into folders.
In order to enable developers to get "the right" sources for their task from TFS, Eclipse users use [Team Project Set Files](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Project_Set_File) to define a set of Eclipse projects (== TFS folders) to get.

Is there a corresponding feature or plugin for IntelliJ IDEA?

I already found the [Project Set Loader Plugin](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7217?pr=idea), which does exactly the right thing, but only for a CVS repository. And we use TFS.

Comment: It would appear that jet brains offers a fairly complete integration of tfs for IntelliJ including workspace support in tfs whic can be used to define the parts of a project visible during development

Comment: @MikeBeeler How would that work?

Comment: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/using-tfs-integration.html

Answer (score 0):

Use [TFS Integration](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?idea&id=4578) and [Project Set Loader](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7217?pr=idea) (This plugin loads the modules referenced in a project set file (PSF) into the current project or updates the modules to the sticky tag given in the project set file.)

Comment: Hm. As I mention in the question, Project Set Loader only works with CVS. It cannot handle the TFS provider.

Comment: After installing TFS Integration Intellij doesn't load, how did you manage to use TFS?